# C# CSVHelper: After BadDataException Reader doesn't continue with next row

Tags: csv, .net-core, csvhelper

that's my first published question, so I hope I'm able explain it comprehensible.

I'm reading a CSV file and want to add correct entries into a list of User objects. Wrong entries (which cause a BadDataException) should be ignored when the flag `ignoreBadCSVEntry` is set to true, otherwise reading the file should be stopped and the list be set to null.

I've seen solutions with setting a local variable `isRecordBad` to true (like mentioned [here](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/803)) but I try to handle it only with exceptions.

The (for a test case malformed) CSV looks like that:

```
"id";"deletedDate";"createDate";"otherAtr"
"000000";"2018-12-4T17:04:34.595+0200";"2019-06-05";"d2"
"WrongDelimiter";"2019-02-29T14:04:34.595+0200","2019-06-05";"d3"
"000001";"2018-12-31T18:04:34.595+0200";"2019-06-05";"d4"
"011111";"2019-01-01T18:04:34.595+0200";"2019-06-05";"d5"
[...]
```

And my code looks the following:

```
try
{
    Configuration csvConfig = new Configuration()
    {
        Delimiter = ";",
        Quote = '"',

        MissingFieldFound = (headerNames, index, context) => throw new CsvHelper.MissingFieldException(context, "Bad entry found at row " + context.RawRow + ": " + context.RawRecord.Replace("\"", "'")),
        BadDataFound = context => throw new BadDataException(context,  String.Format("BadDataFound: Bad entry found at field {0}, \n row {1}: {2}", context.Field, context.RawRow, context.RawRecord.Replace("\"", "'")))
    };

    foreach (string currentFile in csvFiles)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(currentFile))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, csvConfig))
        {
            var moreRecords = true;
            while (moreRecords)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (csv.Read())
                    {
                        var record = new User();
                        record = csv.GetRecord<User>();
                        InsertIntoUserList(record); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        moreRecords = false;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    if (e.GetType() == typeof(FormatException) || 
                        e.GetType() == typeof(BadDataException) || 
                        e.InnerException != null && e.InnerException.GetType() == typeof(MissingFieldException))
                    {
                        if (!ignoreBadCSVEntry)
                        {
                            throw; 
                        }
                        _logger.LogWarning(e.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            _logger.LogDebug("Read List with {0} elements from file(s) in directory {1}.", this.UsersList.Count, sourceDir);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    _logger.LogError("Error while iterating over CSV files in directory {0} ", sourceDir);
    _logger.LogError(e.Message);

    this.List = null;
    throw;
}
```

So the first error message in the inner catch block looks like that:

> BadDataFound: Bad entry found at field 2019-02-29T14:04:34.595+0200,"2019-06-05", 
>       row 3: 'WrongDelimiter';'2019-02-29T14:04:34.595+0200','2019-06-05';

And instead of continuing and reading the next line, more BadDataExceptions will occurr. The following error messages will continue with the bad field and add the next fields with neither delimiters nor quotations after it. Like:

> BadDataFound: Bad entry found at field 2019-02-29T14:04:34.595+0200,"2019-06-05"d3, 
>    row 4: 'd3'
>
> BadDataFound: Bad entry found at field 2019-02-29T14:04:34.595+0200,"2019-06-05"d3000001, 
>    row 5: '000001';

What am I doing wrong here? Why doesn't the reader continue reading at the next line but start with the wrong entry?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Throwing from `BadDataFound` interrupts CsvHelper's processing of that row (like moving to the next line), which is why it continues with the next item after the bad data that was found. You need to put the logic to throw or not in `BadDataFound`.

```cs
BadDataFound = context => {
    if (!ignoreBadCSVEntry)
    {
        throw new BadDataException(context, string.Format("BadDataFound: Bad entry found at field {0}, \n row {1}: {2}", context.Field, context.RawRow, context.RawRecord.Replace("\"", "'")));
    }
    _logger.LogWarning(string.Format("BadDataFound: Bad entry found at field {0}, \n row {1}: {2}", context.Field, context.RawRow, context.RawRecord.Replace("\"", "'")));
}
```

Comment: Actually I'm throwing the exception in ```BadDataFound```. With the inner catch I want to prevent the wrong User getting inserted into the list (without using the isRecordBad flag from the other example mentioned above). Is there a way how to throw different exceptions inside the csv configuration and react on the different exceptions without interrupting the CsvHelper's functionality?

Comment: I would say no. `BadDataFound` is a chance to handle any bad data issues before continuing on with processing the row. When you throw _any_ exception in `BadDataFound` you are skipping the rest of the row processing, leaving `CsvReader` in an unstable state to continue processing.